# error code 1558 column count of mysql.proc is wrong

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb, mysql-workbench

my Problem ist the Following Error Code:
error code 1558 column count of mysql.proc is wrong

It comes up with "can't fetch tables" in the Sql workbench, the "weird" thing is, uploading the tables etc is working and when I connect to the Database I can see them but it can't fetch the tables. Also on myphpadmin everything worked fine.
I have read multiple Posts but none worked,
some said go into the Terminal and do XXX command, but if u sed them it always said this command could not be found.

In the Sql Workbench I have SQL Version 5.7.21 Default Sql version and my MariaDB Server Version is 10.4.14-MariaDB.
(XAMPP)

Any Ideas?

Comment: Check `mysql.proc` table structure, compare it with one shown in [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqlproc-table/) - maybe it is damaged. PS. This is MariaDB-specific system table.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the failing code.

Answer (score 3):

This typically is caused by a database server version binary upgrade without running the mysql_upgrade tool afterwards to apply necessary version dependent changes to the system tables.

After running mysql_upgrade this error should not occur anymore

Comment: i have tried to run my_sql upgrade in my Mac OS Terminal but It doesn't know the command - or do I have to run it somewhere else? I'm new to Databases (school) and my teacher doesn't know o fix it cause its only accruing on my Mac book and not the laptops (windows) of the other students

Comment: mysql_upgrade should be in the same folder as the mysql command line client (unless things on a mac are different than on linux and windows, i don't have one at hand to test)

Getting back to your original text, you wrote "In the Sql Workbench I have SQL Version 5.7.21 Default Sql version and my MariaDB Server Version is 10.4.14-MariaDB. (XAMPP)" 

Do the other students have 10.4.14, too, and where does the 5.7.21 version come from? If a MySQL 5.7.21 full backup was restored on MariaDB 10.4.14, this would cause this kind of error, too (but still would be fixed by mysql_upgrade)

Comment: Can you provide the output of 

SHOW CREATE TABLE mysql.proc